# How to disable owl carousel slider in desktop?

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, owl-carousel

I am using [owlcarousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html).I have to display only images on desktop and in mobile it should be display slider.If i remove scripts,Slider is not working in device.Please check below image for reference. Would you help me in this?
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
 
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
 
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<div id="owl-demo">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you :)

```js
function owlSlider() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
 
      items : 4,
      //itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 
  });
 
};
$(window).resize(function(){
 resizeWin();
});
function resizeWin(){
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
   owlSlider();
}
}
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
 
<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<div id="owl-demo">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-50941625,width-640,resizemode-4/mughal-gardens-in-full-bloom.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay Mr.Charantej, I tried your code but you know i checked on http://www.responsinator.com/ it showing perfectly but when i check on my mobile it showing all image in one line.

Comment: Can you please share the link so that i can review it once again

Comment: It's working now but i have one doubt now.I minimize my browser showing perfectly slider but when i maximized my browser it not looking same.You can also try.